# Convert Web API backward compatible with WCF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, asp.net-web-api

Lets say I have a WCF service `Service1.svc` that contains `GetData(value)`.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    string GetData(int value);
}

public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public string GetData(int value)
    {
        return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
    }
}
```

I also have a client that already auto-generate the proxy to consume this service, something like this:

```
using (var client = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client())
{
    var result = client.GetData(1);
    //Assert.AreEqual("You entered: 1", result);
}
```

Now, I removed that WCF service and replaced it with a new Web API service, something like this:

```
[RoutePrefix("Service1.svc")]
public class DataController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetData")]
    public string GetDataOld(int value)
    {
        return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
    }
}
```

So when I try to use the client `Service1Client()` it doesn't work anymore. I am pretty sure this is possible but what I have to do in order to accomplish this goal?

**Update 05/23/2016**

Since this is not possible, I decided to create a proxy so the client(s) can easily implement the new Restful Web API.

Comment: It all depends on the used binding. If it was a WebHttpBinding then the transport was REST; if not, you'll have to reimplement the client or introduce a translating proxy, which is not trivial.

Answer (score 0):

`WebApi` is designed to be `REST` endpoints, so the wcf way of `var client = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client()` is counter to the concept.

Rather you should try to access it through the url, for your example it'll be something like `~\Service1.svc\GetData\1`. Also check your `route` configuration to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ServiceReference1.Service1Client()` is directly related to WCF. You cannot reuse it for interacting with WebApi endpoints.

If you want a client that interacts with your WebApi endpoints, you will need to write a wrapper client yourself. [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) is my library of choice for such a thing. Example:

```
var client = new RestClient("http://localhost:8000");
int value = 12345;

var request = new RestRequest($"Service1.svc/GetData/{value}", Method.GET);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
var content = response.Content; // returns "You entered: 12345"
```

(untested)

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, and we are currently doing something similar - we replaced our WCF/SOAP service endpoints with WebAPI/JSON endpoints, without changing the client's proxies.

To do this, you have to use the WebHttpBinding and add some more attributes to your service interface so that the proxy generates the right calls:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet]
    string GetData(int value);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method="POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    void PostData(MyDataType data);
}
```

This will make the proxy use HTTP calls, rather than SOAP calls, to access your service. As you can see, this works both for GET and POST requests, and automatically serializes your data as JSON (or XML, if you prefer).

There are more ways to [customize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.webinvokeattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) it - like using the `UriTemplate` property to specify more complex HTTP routes (or have two methods, `GetData` and `PostData`, both map to the same route and differ only by verb, the RESTful way). And there are caveats as well - from what I could see, you can only pass *strings* to GET requests, not ints. But all in all, it works quite well.

Would we have chosen to go with WCF proxies mapped to WebAPI endpoints if we had started the project with WebAPI/REST? Probably not. But this allowed us to switch back-ends with relatively little front-end code changes.